# How to check if menu with specific name exists

Tags: wordpress

How to check if a menu with name, for example 'topnavbar' exists in WordPress 3?

Comment: What do you mean by "menu" exactly? A menu in the back-end?

Comment: I mean the menu that you can make in the admin area. I need to check programmatically if the menu with some name exists and then use it something like this: wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'navbar', 'depth' => '1', 'walker' => $walker));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at the code for the `wp_nav_menu` function, one of the first things it does is get the menu with that name, using the `wp_get_nav_menu_object` function. This function will return the menu, or false if it doesn't exist

Comment: This works for both the menu id ['menu_id'] and menu name ['menu'].

Answer (score 10):

has_nav_menu() sounds like what you're looking for.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu

Comment: Misleading answer! It tests for menu **position**, not menu name / id.

Comment: Misleading comment! It tests **if a menu exists in a specified position**. The comment is misleading because threw me off a bit. I think most people come here looking for has_nav_menu() *( I mean - why would you actually want to know what the user named the menu... )*

From the source of has_nav_menu(): `@return bool Whether location has a menu.`

Comment: "Why would you want to know?" Partly because that's what the asker asked, and that should be enough. If you don't know the answer you shouldn't answer by questioning his motives. I want to know because on my current site the client should have control over some submenus (i.e. create the menus in admin), and have some submenus generated from custom post children, because they are many and the submenu entries should match their published-status.

Comment: "why would you actually want to know what the user named the menu." I do in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

There is conditional tag `is_nav_menu( $id )` which checks if the given id, slug or name is a navigation menu:

```
if ( is_nav_menu( 'topnavbar' ) ) {
    // do something
}
```

Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_nav_menu